# How to generate token without client_secret in Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Security OAuth 2.0 based application, configured with a JDBC and LDAP. As per the OAuth 2.0 specification, client secret must.

When I generate token by using following URL it generates token and works fine:

```
/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_secret=test&client_id=test&username=test&password=test
```

and when I try to generate token without `client_secret` it gives:

> 401: Unauthorized
>
> error_description: "Bad User Credentials"

but I want to generate token without `client_secret` like:

```
/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=test&password=test
```

`securityConfig.java`:

```java
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
 public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter                               {

    private static final int EMBEDDED_LDAP_SERVER_PORT = 33388;

    @Autowired
    private UserAuthenticationProvider userAuthenticationProvider;    

    @Autowired
    private LdapAuthenticationProvider ldapAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    private AuthTokenStore oAuthTokenStore;     

    @Autowired
    private AuthDelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint  delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    @Override
    @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
    @Bean
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList((AuthenticationProvider) ldapAuthenticationProvider,userAuthenticationProvider));
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
         http
             .csrf().disable()
             .sessionManagement()
                  .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                  .and()
             .authorizeRequests()
                  .anyRequest().authenticated()
                  .and()
             .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(delegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint);
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceServerTokenServices tokenService() {

        DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
        tokenServices.setTokenStore(oAuthTokenStore);
        tokenServices.setReuseRefreshToken(true);
        return tokenServices;
    }
```

Comment: If grant type is password you can pass only client_id no need of client secret..like `/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=test&password=test&client_id=CLIENT_ID`

Comment: how can i do with this url ?
/oauth/token?grant_type=password&username=test&password=test‌​&client_id=CLIENT_ID @PrasannaKumar

Comment: Mention the client id in security config and pass that client id...it will return token

Comment: where should i pass client_id in securityConfig and i am using ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter but it is not working @PrasannaKumar

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57081799/3090180

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no easy way around your problem. Spring security interprets the standard very strict:

This is a quote from the OAuth2 spec, [RFC 6749, section 4.3.2 (Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant - Access Token Request)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3.2):

> If the client type is confidential or the client was issued client
> credentials (or assigned other authentication requirements), the
> client MUST authenticate with the authorization server as described
> in Section 3.2.1.

For spring security the password grant always falls into this category. Section 3.2.1 requires client ID and client password.

Also the spring security documentation goes this way:
[28.1.1 Authorization Server](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html#boot-features-security-oauth2-authorization-server)

Unless you want to change the authentication logic of spring security's OAuth2 (not recommended) you are stuck.

From my point of view there is no problem. Client ID and password costs you nothing and bring a little bit more security to your application.

Comment: I don't get this. If I talk to my API using a web client - am I supposed to hard code that `client_id` and `client_secret` somewhere or am I just sending it to the client? I don't see how this makes any sense. ^^

Comment: I've down voted this because I believe it is legitimate to have a non confidential (public) client that does not keep its own client secret using Resource Owner / Password grant and that this is the true answer. Happy to upvote again if I'm proven wrong but in its current form I think this answer is misleading while at the same time sounding authoritative by quoting the spec.